# How to fix InvalidManifestError for pre-commit with black?

Tags: python, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, python-black

Running python `pre-commit` with `black` latest version `23.11.0` leads to a wired `InvalidManifestError`.

snippet from `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 23.11.0
    hooks:
    -   id: black
        types: []
        files: ^.*.pyi?$  # format .py and .pyi files`
```

output message:

```bash
│ │      stdout = 'An error has occurred: InvalidManifestError: \n==> File                       │ │
│ │               /Users/robot/.cache/pre-c'+329                                                 │ │
│ │ stdout_list = [                                                                              │ │
│ │               │   'An error has occurred: InvalidManifestError: \n',                         │ │
│ │               │   '==> File                                                                  │ │
│ │               /Users/robot/.cache/pre-commit/repoxhmwyits/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml\n',         │ │
│ │               │   "==> At Hook(id='black')\n",                                               │ │
│ │               │   '==> At key: stages\n',                                                    │ │
│ │               │   '==> At index 0\n',                                                        │ │
│ │               │   '=====> Expected one of commit, commit-msg, manual, merge-commit,          │ │
│ │               post-checkout, '+86,                                                           │ │
│ │               │   'Check the log at /Users/robot/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log\n'         │ │
│ │               ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you're using an outdated version of pre-commit.  you need to be using at least version 3.2.0 which [introduced the renamed stages](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#320---2023-03-17)

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: @RabihKodeih that's terrible advice -- pip is always going to give you the latest (and official) version of pre-commit.  brew patches pre-commit in some weird ways and pretty often breaks the distribution

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround (because you are stuck with old pre-commit and Python versions like I am) one could use replace the `repo` field with

https://github.com/psf/black-pre-commit-mirror

which does not use the `pre-commit` stage yet.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the cache in `~/.cache/pre-commit/` worked for me